# averaging every nth rows and excluding values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to average every 5 rows but also to exclude in the average values that are less than 50. This is the command to average every 5 rows.

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($L$3,(ROW()-ROW($P$2))*5,,5))
```

This is the command to exclude values less than 50

```
=AVERAGEIF(L3:L8,">50")
```

How do I combine those two in one command?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a colleague of mine, the following works like a gem.

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(OFFSET($L$3,(ROW()-ROW($P$2))*5,,5),">50"),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have Excel 2016, a `SUMPRODUCT` formula will work.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(ROW($A$1:$A100),5)=0)*($A$1:$A$100<50)*$A$1:$A$100)/SUMPRODUCT((MOD(ROW($A$1:$A100),5)=0)*($A$1:$A$100<50)*1)
```

I assumed your data was in `A1:A100` so update that as needed. And in the `MOD` formula, I used 5 for ever 5th row. If you need to change that, change the 5 in `MOD` formulas. Lastly, the formula does not include the value 50 since you stated you wanted less than 50.

Answer (score 0):

## 'Tiny' Differences

### Correction

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$2))*5,,5),">50"),0)
```

### Visualize

Let's first visualize what you're actually doing.

[image]

For every five rows in column `L` you are displaying the average of the values, if they are greater than or equal to 50. (in this example) in column `G`:

```
For L3:L8 in G2,
for L9:L13 in G3,
for L14:L18 in G4 etc.
```

### Issues

- The 1st issue is that the formula is written exclusively for the
  **2nd** row. If you want the first result to be displayed in the first row, the formula will result in a `REF!` error.

  If you want to display the first result in the 1st row you have to
  change `L$2` to `L$1`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$1))*5,,5),">50"),0)
  ```

  or for the **3rd** row you have to change `L$2` to `L$3`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$3))*5,,5),">50"),0)
  ```
- The 2nd issue is that you are doing something in column `L` and for
  no obvious reason you are using column `P` in your formula. You could
  have used any column `Z`, `AN` or `CG`, but your doing stuff in
  column `L`, so use `L`.
- The 3rd issue is that you have locked the columns `$L` which means where
  ever you put the formula in a single row, the result will be the same. If
  you don't lock them, you can copy the formula e.g. to the right and
  it will display the results for columns `M`, `N`, `O` etc.:

  [image]

### Other Formulas

```
=SUM(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$2))*5,,5))
=COUNT(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$2))*5,,5))
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$2))*5,,5))
=SUMIF(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$2))*5,,5),">50")
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$2))*5,,5),">50")
```

`AVERAGEIF` is available in Excel from version 2007, but for older versions the following formula can be used instead:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$2))*5,,5),">"&50)=0,0,SUMIF(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$2))*5,,5),">"&50)/COUNTIF(OFFSET(L$3,(ROW()-ROW(L$2))*5,,5),">"&50))
```

---

It first checks if `COUNTIF` results in `0`. If it does it displays `0`, otherwise it divides `SUMIF` with `COUNTIF`.